# Juice recipe recommendation engine to give me recipes based on the ingredients I already have?

Tags: resources, juice, organization, websites, juicing

Does anyone know of a website where I could enter a bunch of ingredients that I have and it would return a list of possible juice recipes for my juicer?  Like a WolframAlpha for recipes?

I've seen a bunch of juice recipe sites and many times I'm missing just one ingredient, or all the ingredients.  I think it would be cool if I could, at any given time, enter what I have on hand then get a list of possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.supercook.com/

Answer (score 4):

Search engines like that, as you know, are more complicated to build than the standard recipe searches you see in most places, and many websites that have food recipes and are heavily utilized don't have them.

If you want to ultimately be able to make juice based on the ingredients on hand, what I'd recommend is becoming more proficient at matching flavor profiles and knowing what the essentials of juice are.  You can learn more about possible good flavor pairings [at this website](http://www.foodpairing.be/) ([more info about the website's technique for pairing flavors](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/are-some-flavour-pairings-known-to-work-better-than-others-and-if-so-why/8327#8327)).  You can also learn a ton at [khymos.org](http://khymos.org/) or from [The Flavor Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316118400) by Page and Dornenburg.  For learning ratios, start with simple recipes such as [these](http://www.living-foods.com/recipes/juicerecipes.html) or even try and break down your ideal juice by sugar and water components and then look at how much sweetness and water are in each possible ingredient.

If you get stuck on a particular recipe, you can always ask how to improve it here.

Comment: Thanks for all this info justkt, this is very helpful.  I guess just like anything, skill comes with experience, experience comes with time...  I'm still hoping that someone knows of something that can take a mashup of ingredients and make something tasty while I'm working on becoming that something.

Answer (score 1):

http://juicerecipes.com/ Is a great website. They have search by ingredient.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and welcome to the site, Sarah.