# How to make a sauce using sugared citrus rinds?

Tags: sauce, flavor, citrus

I finally separated the citrus rinds (orange and lemon) from  the citrus sugar. All the bits of rind are small. With them I was planning on making a citrus sauce to go on top of my brownies and was wanting help on what flavors would go with citrus rind and how much rind to use?

I have lots of blueberries and a few raspberries available as well.

EDIT:

I ended up using raspberries, citrus (orange/lemon) rind, cranberries and sugar. It tasted so good on the brownies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are noted resources for flavor pairing, many of which you can find on this site.  Check out [flavor](/questions/tagged/flavor).  You'll find:

1. [Why some flavors work better together than others](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/are-some-flavour-pairings-known-to-work-better-than-others-and-if-so-why)
2. [A list of books and websites providing information on flavor combinations](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/flavour-combinations-structural-analysis), including suggestions for

   - [FoodPairing](http://www.foodpairing.be/)
   - [Khymos](http://khymos.org/)
   - [The Flavor Thesaurus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0747599777)
   - [cuuks](http://www.cuuks.com/) (here's a start for your [combo](http://www.cuuks.com/combine.php?composition_id=6383))
   - [The Flavor Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316118400)
3. [How to determine if two ingredients will go well together](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/when-creating-a-recipe-what-determines-whether-2-ingredients-will-go-well-togeth)

For your specific question of what goes well with citrus rind, you already know chocolate is a good match and that you are putting the sauce on brownies.  Nuts in your brownies will be a good match too, especially pecans.  Caraway, thyme, cardamom, or black pepper might add an unexpected note with orange.  Rosemary is a very nice match for lemon.  I recently made cookies using orange zest and black pepper that came out quite well.

If you want the citrus flavor to dominate I would leave out the berries.  Otherwise I'd definitely use the raspberries, which go well with citrus.  The bluberries would be fine, but I wouldn't consider them your best choice.