# Resource for combining flavors

Tags: equipment, flavor, resources

I'm wondering if there is some online resource that compiles different flavors and their combinations.

I'm imagining some site that I could search one tag or several, say "orange" and "cake", and then give me results for different things that have orange as a main flavor (some creamsicle cake) or as a secondary flavor component like in a carrot cake.

I know this is a bit confusing, but if there's anyway I can make this better, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Originally posted as an answer but I realized you are asking only about online resources: "My favorite offline resource is the flavor bible:

It is organized by ingredients alphabetically. Under each ingredient is a table of compatible and contrasting flavors.

Very helpful when I want to do something creative with a particular ingredient I have on hand and I need ideas."

Comment: Have you tried googling "Flavor Combinations"?

Comment: See the answers to this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/flavour-combinations-structural-analysis There are several online tools that you can use.