# Is there a guide for the purpose of each spice?

Tags: spices

I'm wondering if there is a guide image or website that just lists most spices and what their purpose is, sometimes I don't know what spices to add to my food and it would help

Comment: Searching online for "spice guide" brings up many appropriate resources.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2770/28879

Comment: One thing to note is that a single spice doesn't have a single purpose.  Ginger, for example, will have a different effect in curries compared to in cakes (also cinnamon, cloves, and other spices that are used in sweet as well as savoury dishes).  Even beyond that, some spices behave differently when added early in cooking vs late, or in small quantities vs large

Answer (score 3):

There are many:

- [The Kitchn](https://www.thekitchn.com/quick-guide-to-every-herb-and-spice-in-the-cupboard-108770)
- [Food Network](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/articles/guide-to-spices)
- [Greatist](https://greatist.com/health/ultimate-guide-spices#1)
- [Eat Clean Essentials](https://eatcleanessentials.com/blog/complete-beginners-guide-cooking-with-spices/)
- [Spice Hunter](https://spicehunter.com/pages/essential-spice-guide)

Better than the online resources, though, are books, because they can give you more instructions and context in when you'd use a particular spice, and how.  This includes [The New Guide to Spices](https://www.abebooks.com/New-Guide-Spices-Definitive-Visual-Encyclopedia/30933775733/bd), [The Spice Companion](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/533132/the-spice-companion-by-lior-lev-sercarz/),  and others.

Yet even better: just pick up a cookbook for some spice-heavy cuisine (Indian, Middle Eastern, Chinese, Thai, etc.) and start buying the spices needed for those recipes and following the recipes.  One rarely uses spices separately from the food you're cooking, after all.